# UIPickerView in UITableViewCell - how to select values instead of scrolling TableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I've got a custom UITableViewCell that has a label and a UIPickerView. Display works fine, but when I want to select a value in the Picker, the TableView scrolls. What can I do so that the gestures in the cell go to the Picker instead of the whole TableView?

The only solution I could come up with was to set the whole TableView to scrollEnabled = NO. This works for the Picker, but now I can't get to the cells under the custom cell. Control has to be more fine-grained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get hold of the UIGestureRecognizer for each of the two gestures, and tell one it needs to wait for the other to fail.  With one in every cell, that becomes over-wieldy.

Perhaps you should add a control or have the accessory view "bring up" the picker, and then dismiss it when done.

Comment: The short version for me: Probably too complicated to make it work the way I want it to. back to the drawing board to come up with a better UI solution.